# Why does Ruby need to force an Array into string by using "to_a" if it is clear it is a String addition?

Tags: ruby, coercion

For example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > a = ['hello', 'world']
 => ["hello", "world"] 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "foo" + a
TypeError: can't convert Array into String
    from (irb):3:in `+'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "foo" + a.to_s
 => "foo[\"hello\", \"world\"]" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts "foo" + a.to_s
foo["hello", "world"]
```

why can't Ruby automatically convert the array to String?

Comment: How could Ruby possibly know how *you* want *your* array converted to a string?

Comment: the same way `"number of mails: " + n` could have been.

Comment: The title says `to_a` but I think you meant `to_s`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that Ruby *can't*, it's more that it *won't*. It's a [strongly typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language), which means you need to take care of type conversions yourself. This is helpful in catching errors early that result from mixing incompatible types, but requires a little more care and typing from the programmer.

Comment: that's true, even the simple case of `'a' + 1` isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are a special case because you can use string interpolation to call `to_s` implicitly:

```
obj = Object.new.tap {|o|
  def o.to_s
    'object!'
  end
  def o.inspect
    '[object]'
  end
}

"foo: " + obj  # TypeError
"foo: #{obj}"
=> "foo: object!"
```

I redefined `inspect` to show that `to_s` is being called, and not `inspect`. On ruby 1.9, `Object#inspect` calls `to_s`, so if I didn't redefine `inspect`, the above code wouldn't show clearly which method was actually being called during interpolation.

Answer (score -3):

You can make your Ruby automatically convert to String.

```
class Array
  def to_string
    self.unshift("").join(" ")
  end
end

a = ["Hello", "World"]

"foo" + a.to_string
```

I used Ruby for a bit before Rails came out. I just downloaded it again and was playing around, then saw your question.
I may be ignorant or a nutter, but hey... that's my stab at it.

Comment: By doing this, you added a "" element to the beginning of the array. That's a pretty jarring side effect that you should watch for. If you really want a leading space (and I argue you don't in this method) just concatenate one at the beginning.